# HTTP redirect to HTTPS Python

Tags: python, https

I am trying to login to the API with following correct credential, the problem I am facing is, the http URL is redirected to https url as you can see in the terminal section and I get 401 error, which is not correct
as I can use my credentials to log in the API using regular browser.

Can someone tell me how to approach this problem, as I think is a very common issue, but with my lack of understanding of https I am not able to get around this.

```
--------------Program--------------------------------------------
import requests    
authentication = (<username>, <password>)
response = requests.get("http://sdmapi-stage.cloudapps.cisco.com/sdm/api/v0.1/device/?start=1&pagesize=100000",
        allow_redirects=True,
            auth=authentication)
if not response.ok:
        print response.status_code
        return response.status_code

--------------Terminal--------------------------------------------
Starting new HTTP connection (1): sdmapi-stage.cloudapps.cisco.com
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): wwwin-sso-nprd.cisco.com
401
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Session` object instead of a simple get on requests.
(http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/)

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('user', 'pass')
```

Your credentials will be used for further requests